# QProcess::start not launching a process

Tags: qt

I need to launch an executable when I click a button inside my Qt application. To launch an executable, I am using QProcess object.

```
QProcess *executable = new QProcess(this);
executable->start("test.exe");
```

test.exe present on the same location where my Qt application exist.

The problem I am facing here is, when I am debugging, it is launching the test.exe. But when I run without debugging, it is not launching the executable. I dont know what I am missing here.

Comment: Most possibly `QProcess` does not find your `test.exe` file. Try to define the full file path instead.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Connect a slot to the QProcess::error signal, or call executable->error() to see what error, if any, is present : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#error

Comment: I was deleting QProcess object at the end of the function. That was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Directories in which an application tries to find `test.exe` are different when you run the program in debug and from Explorer. Always use full path instead.

If you place `test.exe` file in a folder where your application EXE is located, you can use this:

```
QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).absoluteFilePath("test.exe")
```